# PDO execute() подставляет нули вместо переменных

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
> Что не так с кодом, почему при попытке использовать плейсхолдеры в базу в место каждого значения прилетает 0.

public static function set_data_test(){

  $sql = 'INSERT INTO messages (name, email, message) VALUES (name = :name, email = :email, message = :message)';

  $name ='vasia';
  $email = '@email';
  $message = 'some text';

  $link = self::$link;
  $res = $link->prepare($sql);
  $result = $res->execute(array('name' => $name, 'email' => $email, 'message' => $message));
  $count = $res->rowCount();

  return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PDO всё верно подставляет куда требуется.

Смотрим внимательнее в запрос:

```
INSERT INTO messages (name, email, message) 
    VALUES (name = :name, email = :email, message = :message)
```

Что такое `name = :name`? Я действительно сильно удивился отсутствию ошибки разбора запроса. Оказалось да, так можно. Эффект полностью логичный, специфичный для крайне вольно работающего с типами mysql.

В `values` можно сослаться на значение колонки (вероятно на дефолтное значение или before trigger). С values можно делать подзапросы и любые вычисления.

То есть в колонку `name` вы говорите вставить значение *выражения* `name = :name`, дефолтное значение для name очевидно не равно передаваемому значению, т.е. false, который приводится к 0. Вот этот ноль и наблюдаем в результате.

[sqlfiddle с демонстрацией](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd0e5a/1)

Comment: все верно, и действительно логично, не разобравшись я почему то решил что PDO перед отправкой запроса, присвоит значения справа от точек значениям слева и тогда получиться нормальный запрос, вообщем спасибо вам)

Answer (score 1):

Если верить примерам в [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepare.php#refsect1-pdo.prepare-examples), то не хватает точек:

```
$result = $res->execute(array(':name' => $name, ':email' => $email, ':message' => $message));
                               ^--               ^--                 ^--
```

и сам запрос должен быть

```
INSERT INTO messages (name, email, message) VALUES (:name, :email, :message);
```

а не `name = :name, email = :email, message = :message`

Comment: Точки для execute необязательны, ошибка чуть в другом месте

Comment: Hа счет необязательных точек в курсе, но не работает не так не так((( как по мне здесь всё должно работать не нет, может кто в курсе что еще может провоцировать такое поведение PDO?????

Comment: @АлександрЛычик а, я понял, нужно же `'INSERT INTO messages (name, email, message) VALUES (:name, :email,  :message)';
`

Comment: @Мелкий не сразу заметил `name = :name, email = :email, message = :message`